# How to get single Flex Object by its property value like search() can for Flex Collection

Tags: grav

According to https://learn.getgrav.org/17/advanced/flex/using/object#712b8c68bf0 we can get a single Flex Object from a Flex Collection by the key of the object:

```
{% set contact = grav.get('flex').object('gizwsvkyo5xtms2s', 'contacts') %}
```

However, I think in most cases we don't know the key and would like to get an object by the value of its property for example by a string in the title.

As to Flex Collection, we have the method `search()` if we want to get modified collection by a string in property value and of course we can use this to get collection with one item.

But is there the same method to get a single Flex Object?

I see there is the method `search()` for the Flex Object too. But as I can understand, it's just to determine whether a property contains a string or not only AFTER we have already got the object by its key.

Or if I'm wrong and we can get a single Flex Object by this `search()` method, then how to do that in Twig template? Can you post an example?

So I need something like

```
{% set contact = grav.get('flex').object('contacts').search('Michael', ['first_name'], {'contains': true}) %}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Like with an RDBMS, when searching for a non-indexed field a scan of the entire table is required to test each and every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a function that returns an object by a given property:value.

Instead, you can use `collection.filterBy({ 'first_name': 'michael' })`. https://learn.getgrav.org/17/advanced/flex/using/collection#filterby

If you're certain that `michael` is going to be a value unique to that object and you just want to render it without looping through a collection, you can use Twig's `|first` filter to access the first (only) object in the collection.

```
{% set contacts = grav.get('flex').collection('contacts') %}
{% set collection = contacts.filterBy({ 'first_name': 'michael'}) %}

{{ collection|first.first_name }}
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the `|first` I didn't know about